# How can I have stuff like textboxes or buttons on an image as background in css?

Tags: php, html, css

As you can see here, the 'upload file' and 'choose file' buttons are above he image and I am not able to move them on the image.

[image: screenshot]

```html
<form  class="w3-container " action="add_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position:absolute;z-index:20%;margin-left:50%;">
                <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
            </form>
            <p>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="list_files.php">See all files</a>
            </p>

<div>   
<img src="switzerland_alps_mountains_night_beautiful_landscape_99817_1920x1080.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Can we please see your CSS: You probably need to float the second file input.

Comment: CSS file contains many lines of code which is not possible to paste here. Any thing particular in CSS file? I posted the background code here: 

.w3-transparent{background-color:transparent!important}
.w3-hover-none:hover{box-shadow:none!important;background-color:transparent!important}

@Thomas

Comment: @SanatDeshpande That's a start, but you should edit that into the question, not put it in a comment. It needs to be enough CSS so that we can reproduce the problem. Also, I'm not sure if this influences things, but there's an error in the z-index in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  position: aboslute;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  <button>hi</button>
  <button>hello</button>
</div>
```